# Bash script for speedreading training

Tags: bash, console, shell, quiz

I have coded a speedreading training `bash` script. My targed was to make some experience with `bash` in a funny way.

It essentially does the following:

1. Prints to screen a random number consisting of a default number of digits
2. Erases that number after a default time interval
3. Waits for the user input

   - if the user enters a string starting with a digit (only in this case, <kbd>Enter</kbd> is required as the end-of-input key)

     1. Checks if the answer matches the number that was shown
     2. Updates the number of hits and misses which is always shown on the top right
   - if the user hits <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> the time interval is reduced/increased
   - if the user hits <kbd>h</kbd>/<kbd>l</kbd> the number of digits is reduced/increased
   - if the user hits <kbd>q</kbd> the script exits (*)
   - if the user hits any other key, does nothing
4. Throws the next number (i.e. it goes to step 1 in outer list)

(*) This is the only "clean" way to exit the code; in this respect, the line

```
while [[ "$answer${answer+xxx}" != "xxx" ]]; do # keep going if a non-null answer is provided
```

behaves just like `while true` (and the comment is therefore wrong), as `answer` is unset before `while`, and it becomes set only when the `[0-9]` case is entered, in which case it becomes and remains non-empty.

The script is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/Aster89/miscellaneous/blob/60e8b88798902d3d43fc428cd59a6cf5d87801f0/blink).

```
#!/bin/bash
# terminal based speedreading tester
# links that helped me:
#  - https://superuser.com/q/835824/597763

# activate extended regex
shopt -s extglob

# fall back on defaults
BLINK_DIGITS=${BLINK_DIGITS:-5}
BLINK_INTERVAL=${BLINK_INTERVAL:-0.5}
BLINK_QUIT=${BLINK_QUIT:-q}
BLINK_INCREMENT_DIGITS=${BLINK_INCREMENT_DIGITS:-l}
BLINK_DECREMENT_DIGITS=${BLINK_DECREMENT_DIGITS:-h}
BLINK_DECREMENT_TIME=${BLINK_DECREMENT_TIME:-j}
BLINK_INCREMENT_TIME=${BLINK_INCREMENT_TIME:-k}

# initialize score
right=0
wrong=0

# define functions
generate_number() {
  gen=
  while (( ${#gen} < $BLINK_DIGITS )); do
    gen=$gen$RANDOM
  done
  echo ${gen:0:$BLINK_DIGITS}
}

center_vertically() {
  print_header
  lines=$(tput lines)
  for (( i = 0; i < $lines/2; i++ )); do
    printf "\n"
  done
}

center_horizontally() {
  width=$1
  cols=$(tput cols)
  for (( i = 0; i < ($cols - ${#width})/2; i++ )); do
    printf " "
  done
}

print_spaces() {
  eval "printf ' %.0s' {1..$1}"
}

print_header() {
  # prepare left part of first two lines (I can't use here-strings/documents since
  # some computation has to be donw with the length of the strings, provided I want to flush
  # some text to the right)
  selected_time_interval="Time interval: $BLINK_INTERVAL seconds ([$BLINK_DECREMENT_TIME] reduces, [$BLINK_INCREMENT_TIME] increases)"
  string_length="String length: $BLINK_DIGITS digits ([$BLINK_DECREMENT_DIGITS] removes digit, [$BLINK_INCREMENT_DIGITS] adds digit)"

  # compute scores and align them to the right
  trim=$(( ${#right} - ${#wrong} ))
  (( trim < 0 )) &&  score_plus="Score: ✓ $(print_spaces ${trim#-})$right" ||  score_plus="Score: ✓ $right"
  (( trim > 0 )) && score_minus="       ✗ $(print_spaces ${trim#-})$wrong" || score_minus="       ✗ $wrong"
  max_length=$(( ${#score_plus} > ${#score_minus} ? ${#score_plus} : ${#score_minus} ))

  # fill space in between and print the two lines
  cols=$(tput cols)
  printf "$selected_time_interval$(print_spaces $(( $cols - ${#selected_time_interval} - $max_length )))$score_plus\n"
  printf "$string_length$(print_spaces $(( $cols - ${#string_length} - $max_length )))$score_minus"
  echo "[$BLINK_QUIT] quits, all other keys regenerate the number"
}

redraw_screen() {
  clear
  center_vertically
  center_horizontally $number
}

decrement_time() {
  BLINK_INTERVAL="${BLINK_INTERVAL::$((${#BLINK_INTERVAL}-1))}$((${BLINK_INTERVAL:$((${#BLINK_INTERVAL}-1))} - 1))"
  (( ${BLINK_INTERVAL:$((${#BLINK_INTERVAL}-1))} == 0 )) && BLINK_INTERVAL="${BLINK_INTERVAL}9"
}

increment_time() {
  (( ${BLINK_INTERVAL##0.} == 9 )) && return 1
  BLINK_INTERVAL=${BLINK_INTERVAL%%[1-9]*}$((${BLINK_INTERVAL##0.*(0)} + 1))
  (( ${BLINK_INTERVAL:$((${#BLINK_INTERVAL} - 1))} == 0 )) && BLINK_INTERVAL=${BLINK_INTERVAL/0.0/0.} && BLINK_INTERVAL=${BLINK_INTERVAL%%0}
}

quit() {
  # clear screen and exit
  clear
  exit 0
}

# main loop
while [[ "$answer${answer+xxx}" != "xxx" ]]; do # keep going if a non-null answer is provided
  # generate number
  number=$(generate_number $BLINK_DIGITS)

  # show number for short time
  redraw_screen
  printf $number
  sleep $BLINK_INTERVAL

  # erase the number (go back, overwrite with spaces, go back again)
  eval "printf '\b%.0s' {1..${#number}}"
  eval "printf ' %.0s'  {1..${#number}}"
  eval "printf '\b%.0s' {1..${#number}}"

  read -rn 1 first_char
  case $first_char in
    $BLINK_QUIT )
      quit
      ;;
    $BLINK_DECREMENT_DIGITS )
      (( BLINK_DIGITS > 1 )) && (( BLINK_DIGITS-- ))
      ;;
    $BLINK_INCREMENT_DIGITS )
      (( BLINK_DIGITS < $cols - 1 )) && (( BLINK_DIGITS++ ))
      ;;
    $BLINK_DECREMENT_TIME )
      decrement_time
      ;;
    $BLINK_INCREMENT_TIME )
      increment_time
      ;;
    [0-9] )
      redraw_screen
      # erase $first_char
      printf '\b%.0s'
      # use $first_char as a default to have it printed again
      # the leading space is to allow backspacing on the first digit
      # without the all leading space being erased all together
      read -i " $first_char" -e answer
      if (( $answer == $number )); then
        (( right++ ))
      else
        (( wrong++ ))
      fi
      ;;
  esac

done

(( $? == 0 )) && quit || exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> # fall back on defaults
> BLINK_DIGITS=${BLINK_DIGITS:-5}
> BLINK_INTERVAL=${BLINK_INTERVAL:-0.5}
> BLINK_QUIT=${BLINK_QUIT:-q}
> BLINK_INCREMENT_DIGITS=${BLINK_INCREMENT_DIGITS:-l}
> BLINK_DECREMENT_DIGITS=${BLINK_DECREMENT_DIGITS:-h}
> BLINK_DECREMENT_TIME=${BLINK_DECREMENT_TIME:-j}
> BLINK_INCREMENT_TIME=${BLINK_INCREMENT_TIME:-k}
> ```

This is exactly the right way to do this.  Good job.

---

> ```
> # activate extended regex
> shopt -s extglob
> ```

Is this even needed?

---

> ```
> generate_number() {
>   gen=
>   while (( ${#gen} < $BLINK_DIGITS )); do
>     gen=$gen$RANDOM
>   done
>   echo ${gen:0:$BLINK_DIGITS}
> }
> ```

This is biased because the first digit of `RANDOM` will rarely be zero, and the maximum value of 32767 means you get more 1-3 than 4-9.  Keep only the ones digit: it nearly eliminates the bias and avoids the need to truncate at the end.

```
for (( i=0; i < BLINK_DIGITS; ++i )); do 
    gen+=$(( RANDOM % 10 )); 
done
```

---

> ```
> center_vertically() {
>   print_header
>   lines=$(tput lines)
>   for (( i = 0; i < $lines/2; i++ )); do
>     printf "\n"
>   done
> }
> ```

You can use the `LINES` variable here with a [`printf` idiom to repeat a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash) (which only works with constants because `{1..n}` doesn't allow variables):

```
printf -vblank "\n%.0s" {1..1000}
echo "${blank:0:LINES/2}"
```

---

> ```
> print_spaces() {
>   eval "printf ' %.0s' {1..$1}"
> }
> ```

`printf` can repeat spaces natively, by supplying a width to `%s`.  This function can be reused by `center_horizontally()`:

```
print_spaces() { printf "%${1}s" ""; }

center_horizontally() { print_spaces $(( ( COLUMNS - ${#1} ) / 2 )); }
```

---

> ```
> trim=$(( ${#right} - ${#wrong} ))
> …
> max_length=$(( ${#score_plus} > ${#score_minus} ? ${#score_plus} : ${#score_minus} ))
> ```

You can assign inside expresssions:

```
(( trim = ${#right} - ${#wrong} ))
(( max_length = ${#score_plus} > ${#score_minus} ? ${#score_plus} : ${#score_minus} ))
```

---

> ```
> decrement_time() {
>   BLINK_INTERVAL="${BLINK_INTERVAL::$((${#BLINK_INTERVAL}-1))}$((${BLINK_INTERVAL:$((${#BLINK_INTERVAL}-1))} - 1))"
>   (( ${BLINK_INTERVAL:$((${#BLINK_INTERVAL}-1))} == 0 )) && BLINK_INTERVAL="${BLINK_INTERVAL}9"
> }
>
> increment_time() {
>   (( ${BLINK_INTERVAL##0.} == 9 )) && return 1
>   BLINK_INTERVAL=${BLINK_INTERVAL%%[1-9]*}$((${BLINK_INTERVAL##0.*(0)} + 1))
>   (( ${BLINK_INTERVAL:$((${#BLINK_INTERVAL} - 1))} == 0 )) && BLINK_INTERVAL=${BLINK_INTERVAL/0.0/0.} && BLINK_INTERVAL=${BLINK_INTERVAL%%0}
> }
> ```

This is really ugly and it fails if the user provides an integer value for `BLINK_INTERVAL`.

You could take a value in milliseconds (or tenths of seconds) and manipulate that; it would be pure bash but still kind of ugly.  I think the best solution is to use a tool that does floating point calculations.  `bc` is suitable but not installed by default on some distributions.  `awk` is up to the task and universally available.

Put the logic in a single function.

```
adjust_time() { 
    BLINK_INTERVAL=$( awk -vb=$BLINK_INTERVAL -voffset=$1 'BEGIN { print b + offset/10 }' ) 
}

increment_time() { 
    adjust_time 1
}

decrement_time() { 
    adjust_time -1
}
```

---

> ```
> printf "$selected_time_interval$(print_spaces $(( $cols - ${#selected_time_interval} - $max_length )))$score_plus\n"
> printf "$string_length$(print_spaces $(( $cols - ${#string_length} - $max_length )))$score_minus"
> ```

Let `printf` handle the spacing for you.  It's a bad habit to put variable data inside the format string; use `%s` instead:

```
printf "%s%$(( COLUMNS - ${#selected_time_interval} - max_length ))s%s\n" $selected_time_interval "" $score_plus
printf "%s%$(( COLUMNS - ${#string_length} - max_length ))s%s" $string_length  "" $score_minus
```

---

> ```
> while [[ "$answer${answer+xxx}" != "xxx" ]]
> ```

This is hacky.  Just test the length of `answer`:

```
while (( ${#answer} ))
```

---

> ```
>       (( BLINK_DIGITS < $cols - 1 )) && (( BLINK_DIGITS++ ))
> ```

Use `COLUMNS`, then it remains correct even if the user resizes the terminal during a run.

---

> ```
>    if (( $answer == $number )); then
>      (( right++ ))
>    else
>      (( wrong++ ))
>    fi
> ```

This can be condensed to one expression.  `$` inside `(( … ))` are not needed for simple variables that contain a number.

```
(( answer == number ? right++ : wrong++ ))
```

---

> ```
> (( $? == 0 )) && quit || exit
> ```

Expressions test for zero by default.  This could be shortened to:

```
(( $? )) && exit || quit
```

But all `quit` does is clear the screen and exit normally.  Just attach `clear` to the loop, and the `quit` function can go away.

```
while (( ${#answer} )); do 
    …
done && clear
exit
```

---

Finally, tell bash to exit on undefined variables, because you shouldn't have any:

```
set -u
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough review! About `shopt -s extglob`, I tend to put it otherwise, should I make use of extended regexes, I would find myself scratching my head for hours, questioning my memory and the books, before discovering for the `n`th time that I've simply forgot this setting. About `RANDOM` is Benford's law the reason for what you say? Wow for `LINES`, so easy! It looks like reading good `bash` books is never enough. _You can assign inside expresssions_: in principle I know this (`(( BLINK_DIGITS-- ))`), but thank you for pointing out other places where I didn't make use of it.

Comment: _This is really ugly_: I completely agree with you, and if `awk` is really so universally available, then I will follow also this advise of yours. Yes, I definitely have to use `printf` more properly. _This is hacky_: another place where I didn't make use of what I know already. Like `LINES`, like `COLUMNS`, thank you. Wow, I didn't know `?:` was available! Last suggestion on `set -u` is illuminating!

Comment: I will test all your suggestions and accept the answer :)

Comment: re: RANDOM, it's just that the numbers have an upper limit that is not a power of 10.  Like if you generate random numbers 0-19, the number will >9 about half the time, so the digit "1" appears way too often.  Same idea with a max of 32767: every five-digit number has a biased digit in it.  It's not really Benford's because "2" is over-represented just as much as "1".  Normal probability distributions (of which this is one) do not exhibit Benford's law in general, and а random value 0-99999 won't exhibit it at all.

Comment: Have you missed the `echo $gen` in `generate_number` just to write one line less, or are you implying a non-`echo` way to return `gen`?

Comment: I'm only rewriting the loop there.  You still need to `echo` the result  (or have the caller reference `$gen` itself) and you still need `gen=` to initialize to empty value.

Comment: As I use `gen+=`, `gen=` to initialize is not really needed, is it? Concerning `center_vertically`, my understanding is that you `printf` 1000 `\n`s into `blank` (btw, I couldn't find `-v` in `man printf`...; plus, I my deduction is that the space after `-v` is optional: is this correct?), and then you only `echo` `LINES/2` of them. Why can't I see the effect of those two commands if I run them in the terminal? Besides, did you intentionally avoid using `eval` to stick `$(( LINES/2 ))` into `printf`?

Comment: `+=` appends; value persists across function calls. You need to say `local gen` to localize it to the function, or init to empty every time with `gen=`.  Use `help printf` not man as printf is builtin. Pasting those two lines into terminal empties half my screen; if it doesn't work, make sure `LINES` is defined (should always be, if `TERM` is set) and that you're using the bash-builtin `printf` (no alias/function overriding it). I did intentionally avoid `eval`; using it almost always adds complexity and weird failure modes; best avoided in most cases.

Comment: My bad on the two lines which empty half screen! I had forgotten the `"` in `echo "${blank:0:LINES/2}"`, so `bash` was collapsing all the newlines. Any idea why there's no `gen=` in my script and the numbers do not accumulate? (If I run the function separately, I get a `gen` of increasing length, as you suggested in your last comment.)

Comment: Maybe you're only calling the function once?  If nothing is resetting the value, I can't explain why it wouldn't continue to grow.

Comment: Ok, if you put only `gen() { x+="x"; echo $x; }` in a file and `source` it, then running `gen` will actually increase the length of `x`, wherease `echo $(gen)` will not. I think it's because the latter command runs `gen` in a subshell, thus preventing the `x` variable from being persistent.

Comment: Oh, I had forgotten to underline that the script is made to allow backspacing on all the inserted character. But if you backspace beyond the first character the cursor jumps back to left border of the terminal. This is unwanted, but I don't know how to avoid it.

Comment: that is a quirk of your terminal emulator; mine doesn't do that.  The next step for this kind of application is to use `stty raw` (so keypresses don't echo, for example) and ANSI escape sequences to position the cursor (instead of printing blanks).  You can also [read the cursor position with escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575037/how-to-get-the-cursor-position-in-bash), and use that to decide how it will affect the output